# What causes SQL Server high network latency?

Tags: sql-server

I am using this command https://docs.dbatools.io/#Test-DbaNetworkLatency to test network latency with SQL Server 2016. And it gives me 100ms network latency result (from `NetworkOnlyTotal` output). However, if I ping the sql server instance I get only 11ms. I wonder what causes the extra 90ms latency in SQL Server. Is it expected? Or what configuration should I look at?

I tried with the `-Count` parameter and found that the `NetworkOnlyTotal` doesn't change too much or sometimes even dropped. Does this value mean average?

See below two examples, one is to run query 1 time while the other is to run the query 10 times. The result about `NetworkOnlyTotal` is even better for 10 times query. From its name, it looks like it is the total time of the 10 requests. But why is the value dropping?

```
Test-DbaNetworkLatency  -SqlCredential $credential -SqlInstance $instance -Count 1

output:
ExecutionCount     : 1
Total              : 141.55 ms
Average            : 141.55 ms
ExecuteOnlyTotal   : 69.13 ms
ExecuteOnlyAverage : 69.13 ms
NetworkOnlyTotal   : 72.42 ms
```

```
Test-DbaNetworkLatency -SqlCredential $credential -SqlInstance $instance -Count 10

output:
ExecutionCount     : 10
Total              : 180.33 ms
Average            : 18.03 ms
ExecuteOnlyTotal   : 127.38 ms
ExecuteOnlyAverage : 12.74 ms
NetworkOnlyTotal   : 52.95 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder what causes the extra 90ms latency in SQL Server. Is it expected?

Probably the one-time connection stuff.

1) Establishing a TCP/IP session

2) Negotiating connection protocol encryption

3) Logging in and creating a session

Try a higher `-Count`  Establishing a connection and a session take some time, and shouldn't really be counted as "network latency", as clients will hold open and reuse connections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set a higher value for Count=100 and the NetworkOnlyTotal drops a lot. So `NetworkOnlyTotal` is not the total network latency of the 100? Is it average value?  Does this mean the rest 99 requests are reusing the opened connection which skip the three steps you listed there?

Answer (score 1):

The description of the product indicates that "It will then output how long the entire connection and command took, as well as how long only the execution of the command took."  Additionally, it says that it will execute the command three times.  And the tool will need to take a little time to authenticate the connection with SQL Server.  So, it seems reasonable to me.